# AWS Lambda Function URL error when submitting JSON request body: unreachable end point

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We enable the new Function URL feature for an AWS Lambda function.

CORS is enabled. GET/POST/OPTIONS methods are allowed. The function is public -- no authorization required.

Hitting the URL from the browser invokes the function.

Hitting the URL from Postman with GET/POST invokes the function -- if you provide an empty request body.

However, defining a JSON request body causes the same URL to be unreachable.

Why?

Comment: You would have to provide full reproducible examples of the lambda code and your json, and how exactly are you invoking the function.